# Filtering out IPv6 multicast address range

Tags: c, ipv6, multicast

For a given IPv6 address represented in a `struct sockaddr_in6` data type, I want to know whether or not the address is in the multicast [address range](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml) or not.

For instance, I want a function `is_ipv6_multicast()` that works as follows

```
struct sockaddr_in6* sa6;
...
if (is_ipv6_multicast(sa6)) {
    // do one thing
} else {
    // do another
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: As @dbush points out, it's very easy to determine whether or not it is a multicast address. The harder part is determining what kind of multicast based on the flags and scopes. Some multicast addresses are invalid, depending on how the flags are set (e.g. if the R flag is set, bot the P and T flags must be set, too, and if one or both are not set, it is an invalid multicast address).

Answer (score 3):

[IPv6 multicast addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#IPv6) have a value of `0xFF` in the first byte.  So you can test it like this:

```
int is_ipv6_multicast(struct sockaddr_in6* sa6) {
    return (sa6->sin6_addr.s6_addr[0] == 0xff);
}
```